# Debugging MFC: "mfc100.dll" cannot find or open pdb

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, debug-symbols

I'm trying to step into MFC source code while debugging. However, Visual Studio apparently has problems with loading the appropriate symbols:

> C:\WINDOWS\symbols\dll\mfc100.i386.pdb: PDB does not match image.

I checked other questions on SO, often it is recommended to enable "symbol servers". This is not helping though, because it only seems to download a minimal PDB file (~2 MB) instead of a PDB file that actually enables you to step into the source (~20 MB).

According to [Cannot load symbols for mfc100.dll](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/119bfcea-eceb-4680-85d1-f004c4438673/cannot-load-symbols-for-mfc100dll-version-1003031901?forum=vcgeneral) I should download a full symbol package from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028. I did that, but it doesn't help either because this package does not actually include symbols for mfc100.dll at all.

Next thing I tried is copying PDB files from another system. On my local Win7 OS I have a mfc100.i386.pdb from 2011-06-10 (24.708 KB). On the system I debug I have mfc100.i386.pdb from 2010-03-18 (23.732 KB). Both do "not match image" though.

So where should I get the correct and full symbol files from?

OS: Windows 8 x86. Visual Studio 2013 with VS 2010 C++ project. mfc100.dll version: `10.00.40219.01`

WinDbg `!sym noisy` output:

```
************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
OK                                             C:\Windows\symbols\dll
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: c:\windows\symbols\dll
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: c:\windows\symbols\dll
0:000> .reload
Reloading current modules

DBGHELP: c:\windows\symbols\dll\mfc100.i386.pdb - mismatched pdb
DBGHELP: c:\windows\symbols\dll\dll\mfc100.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: c:\windows\symbols\dll\symbols\dll\mfc100.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc100.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: mfc100.i386.pdb - file not found
DBGHELP: Couldn't load mismatched pdb for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc100.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc100.dll
DBGHELP: mfc100 - no symbols loaded

************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
mfc100                 PDB not found : c:\windows\symbols\dll\symbols\dll\mfc100.i386.pdb
                Unable to locate the .pdb file in this location
```

Comment: The pdbs allow accurate call stacks to be displayed and not source code, for that you need the source which you will not see unless you work in the MS dev team

Comment: @EdChum I'm talking about the source in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc. So I do have what I need (without being MS dev).

Comment: OK, my bad I misunderstood the problem. So even if you set the symbol server to ` http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols ` or download the ms symbols it still fails? What happens when you attach WinDbg, does this still fail the pdb signature match?

Comment: @EdChum No it does not fail (and shows function names in the stack), but as I said in my question these minimal PDB files don't allow me to step into the source. Windbg doesn't like my PDB files either: `*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mfc100.dll`

Comment: There is this link:http://qualapps.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/symbols-for-mfc-source-code.html and also a remark on this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fddce63-b971-41c6-a12b-55ae4211a4fd/unable-to-step-into-visual-studio-2010-mfc-source-code?forum=vcgeneral by Jeff Booher: 'It turns out that deleting the "mfc100ud.i386.pdb" folder from my local symbol cache and disabling Microsoft public symbol stores fixed this. ' have you tried this?

Comment: @EdChum I already found that post but it doesn't help (he actually has a different issue than I have). And yes, I deleted the PDF file from the symbol server cache and disabled the symbol server.

Comment: In that case I would raise this with MS as it seems specific to `MFC100.dll`, sorry I couldn't help further. I'd add the tag windows to see if it gets noticed by MS guys on SO

Comment: Do:        >!sym noisy
           >.reload
And you'll get more info about why the symbol load is failing.(debugger displays info about its search for symbols)

Comment: @SChepurin Thx, I added the WinDbg output. Hope this helps.

Comment: The only option i can think of - "Check the version of the CRT in VC directory where VS2010 is installed. There should be a redist directory in there and under that is the CRT. Check the version of these files and see if they have the same version as the ones in your system32 directory.(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/2792e510-e156-4a99-9d7b-d42c77122dd4/mismatch-between-the-pdb-and-the-dll-for-msvcr100dll)

Comment: Pay attention to this - "Those symbols should be matched to the version that VS uses, so they can get out of sync if you install a version of the VC redist which is newer than what VS is currently using."

Comment: @SChepurin Ah, that got me on the right track. Installing SP1 of VS2010 did the trick :) Do you want to post this as answer so that I can give you reputation?

Comment: @floele - I will post this as an answer to make it easier for everyone interested to find the possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in this [MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/2792e510-e156-4a99-9d7b-d42c77122dd4/mismatch-between-the-pdb-and-the-dll-for-msvcr100dll) (by Crescens2k) -

> Those symbols should be matched to the version that VS uses, so they can get out of sync if you install a version of the VC redist which is newer than what VS is currently using.
>   Check the version of the CRT in VC directory where VS2010 is installed. There should be a redist directory in there and under that is the CRT. Check the version of these files and see if they have the same version as the ones in your system32 directory. These normally should match. If they don't then check for updates for VS. The latest version should be 10.0.40219.325 so make sure that VS has been updated to use that.

And later -

> ...try manually applying the MFC security update. ... and seeing if that fixes everything.

Happily, with WinDbg tool you could locate your problem to mismatched symbols, and an advice from experienced programmer (Crescens2k) helped to solve the painfully ugly problem of versions mismatch from "DLL hell".

Comment: I need to mention that the "update" I installed which solved the problem was `VS 2010 SP1`, which I skipped on this machine because I was going to use VS2013 anyway.